# Why is Flexbox creating unnecesary spacing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm writing a code where I need to evenly place cards next to each other with rows when using flex. However, I'm getting some spacing on the right side and can't work out a reason why is that happening. I tried inspecting the element, but it just shows the entire card extends to the right, but there is no real reason behind why it does that. I've scrolled through CSS code, and there's no additional width on the right.

```
<section id="jobs">
    <!--Employing cards-->
    <div class="container-fluid container-fluid-shorter bg-white">

        <!--Assistant card-->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
                <div class="card width-37">
                    <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h6 class="card-title font-weight-lighter pb-3">Custom units</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">
                        <h4 class="text-grey font-weight-light text-capitalize pb-3 pt-3">home page hero</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
                <div class="card width-37">
                    <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h5 class="card-title font-weight-lighter pb-3">Vlastní jednotky</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                        <h4 class="text-grey font-weight-light text-capitalize pb-3 pt-3">home page hero</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3">
                <div class="card width-37">
                    <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h5 class="card-title font-weight-lighter pb-3">Vlastní jednotky</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                        <h4 class="text-grey font-weight-light text-capitalize pb-3 pt-3">home page hero</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of employing cards section-->
</section>
```

Adjustments I've made to the CSS :

```
.width-37{
    max-width: 37.5vh;
}
.card-body{
    padding-left: 0; !important;
    padding-right: 0; !important;
}
```

I'm trying to place all the items in the row where there is a small spacing between each item and all items will create rows as you set rows for different screen sizes large, medium, small. For some reason flex item is doing spacing on the right side of each item there is. It is 480 pixels wide and 180 height. I would like it to be 180 x 180 pixels so same height and width. Anyone got an idea on why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why are you using 37.5vh?

Comment: Sure will do hungerstar!

Comment: It's the perfect width Zim.

Comment: You're setting the width of the card to be 37.5% of the viewport height. I'm not sure you want to do that. If the height is very minimal, everything will begin to overflow. What is wrong with the width the column classes provide? Is the card too wide?

Comment: Exactly. The card is too wide and I was trying to change that. I'm new to this so I don't know much about it yet. Is there a better solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: @TH3R34LS3V3NF1V3S1XN1N3 So you want three items per row, but have minimal width? Possibly a fixed width? It might help to provided a simple mockup of the layout you are attempting to achive. You may not need to use Bootstrap rows and columns.

Comment: Yes. I need to have small width in between the cards. But the card should not be too wide the ideal max-width I was looking for was the 37.5vh. Ideally the card would get couple of pixels smaller as the browser windows would become smaller.

Comment: @TH3R34LS3V3NF1V3S1XN1N3 do you understand that `37.5vh` is a relative unit? Your viewport might be `800px` in height and thus `37.5vh = 300px` and my viewport is `400px` in height and thus `37.5vh = 150px`. Are you intending for the width of these to be some fraction of the height? How many items should there be per row? Is it limited to three items? Or can it be _"how ever many will fit in the horizontal space?"_

Comment: I'm trying to go for 6 items when using large sized screen. 3 items when using medium. 1 item when using small (mobile).

Comment: And yes I understand view heights are relative to screen size.

Comment: I suggest updating your question with more details, specifically, what the intended outcome should be. Otherwise, you're not going to get a lot of traction.

Answer (score 1):

```
.width-37{
    max-width: 37.5vh;
}
```

This is causing the spacing on right side. Also, there should be no **;** before **!important**

Comment: I've changed width to "37vh" and removed the ";" before !important. Still no results but thanks for trying!

Comment: @TH3R34LS3V3NF1V3S1XN1N3 `max-width` and `width` are not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how block level elements are rendered and not a Flexbox specific issue. Block level elements always take up the full width of the containing element. If you set a width on a block level element, and it does not fill the containing element, the remaining space will be filled with margin.

**Example**

```css
div {
  min-height: 24px;
}

div:nth-child( 1 ) {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div:nth-child( 2 ) {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
}

div:nth-child( 3 ) {
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

The default flow of content is left to right and why the element is to the left. All the space to the right of each element is margin. This is what is happening inside of your Bootstrap column elements.

Comment: This is it! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**This is the why** 
*Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.
[Documentation here](https://getbo*otstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

In order to remove the padding on your gutter you can add the class no-gutters to your row.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a gutter issue. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tk9Lexj/).

Comment: I just checked. Adding .no-gutters to the parent row removes the 15px on either side of each child column.

Comment: OP is limiting the size of block level content withing a column, thus creating a large amount of space (margin) to the right of that element. Removing gutters removes a tiny fraction of that space and does not explain why all that space is appearing to the right of the target element to begin with - which is the original question.